# Is it possible to send styled link with ACTION_SEND in android

Tags: android, whatsapp, facebook-messenger

I want to send a styled link like: [StackOverFlow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) via ACTION_SEND in android.
Especially I want to use WhatsApp and Facebook Messenger.
Is there any way to make this.
Thank you.

Comment: the link is actually just a text, which is processed by some app.: `<a href="stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a>`. So that depends on the receiving app, if it can convert this code to a *styled link*. You have nothing to do with it wfor your side.

Comment: @VladMatvienko is there any other way to beautify this text?

Comment: no. At least I don't know the way.